# c++ Windows UTF16 L String constant

Tags: utf-16

In C++ there is the following statement

```
wstring tester = L"Работа Центра";
```

we set the console output

```
int res = _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

then we try

```
wcout << "tester " << tester << endl << flush;
```

and we get on the console...

```
 tester D D°D±D_Ñ,D° D▌DµD½Ñ,Ñ?D°
```

So trying to figure out what is happening here instead of getting the proper output.

Is this a code page problem?

Comment: Looks like we have found the issue. L"" is not in the format that we think it is (not UTF16). Need to do "Работа Центра" to a std::string and then convert to a wstring with something like the UNICODE routines.

Comment: `wstring` and `L"..."` are based on the `wchar_t` data type, which is not 16-bit on all platforms.  On some platforms, it is 32-bit instead.  On those platforms, it will not be UTF-16. That is why the new C++11 standard added new `char16_t` and `u"..."` for handling UTF-16 specifically.